# Is there a way to save the ETag value from Amazon S3 using the Shrine gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, shrine

I am using the Shrine gem to upload files to Amazon S3. Is there any way to retrieve the ETag value for a file and save it to the database after it has been uploaded? Ideally I would like to access the ETag value in the upload response to avoid having to do another request to Amazon.

I see ETag referenced a number of times in the gem but am not seeing a straightforward way: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ashrinerb%2Fshrine%20etag&type=code

Answer (score -1):

I am not a Ruby on Rails developer, but here is something that I found might be helpful to you.

As per [Shrine 2.17.0 documentation - Other improvements](https://shrinerb.com/docs/release_notes/2.17.0#other-improvements):

> The `derivation_endpoint`, `rack_response`, and `download_endpoint` plugins now include `ETag` in the headers of responses, preventing the `Rack::ETag` middleware from buffering the response body.

So, you can use [Rack Response](https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/rack_response) plugin to convert an `UploadedFile` object into a triple consisting of **status**, **headers**, and **body**. From there, you can retrieve the `ETag` value from the headers.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that but that Etag method is not the same as the one calculated by Amazon: https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/2df79e244fba5d45adf5b5969433c0135d790388/lib/shrine/plugins/rack_response.rb#L90